# Reading all data coming to my web browser

Tags: http, browser, sniffing

How can I read all data (low level data, encrypted data, etc.) coming to my web-browser? The data can be from different servers. Further I want to parse these data so it should be in some format. I just want to know the structure of data and how can I read and parse it (in "C" or "Java" languages). It is related to browser development.

Comment: Retagged this to something much more likely to get an answer.  This question has nothing to do with Java or C. (or parsing)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could have a look at [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Very nice program to find out about network data; and you can specify filters so it's not too hard to filter out everything going to a browser.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP specification tells you the "structure" of the data.

For intercepting it, you might be able to write a browser plugin (see, for example, FireBug). Otherwise, your best bet is with a local proxy that you configure your browser to talk to.

Or a network sniffing tool like tcpdump or wireshark.

Comment: There is also LiveHTTPHeaders firefox plugin, which show HTTP headers get from the server.